# TablecellRenderer setForeground only on certain characters in cell

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm trying to create a JTable where in one column certain characters have a different color than the rest.

Text1test

Text2test

Text4test

In this example, I want the numbers to be blue, the rest black (the lines represent the cells of the column). Is this possible? I only found answers how to color the complete text of a cell with TableCellRenderer.

Comment: I would suggest to tag your question additionally with `swing` and `java` to help attract more attention.

Comment: Implement  a TableCellRenderer. There's lots of examples if you search the web.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72237036/131872 for an approach that allows you to split the text into multiple components. Each components can have a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) may return any AWT [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html), so you could subclass [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html) and overwrite [paintComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) to tokenize your text and paint each token in an appropriate color. And indeed, this might be the most efficient way to solve your problem.

A less involved solution would be leveraging [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLabel.html)'s support for rendering HTML-formatted text. Again, the idea would be tokenizing your text and coloring the tokens as appropriate. E.g.

```
class MarkupRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
  private final DefaultTableCellRenderer dtcr;
  private final Pattern digits;

  MarkupRenderer() {
    dtcr = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    digits = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
    JTable table,
    Object value,
    boolean isSelected,
    boolean hasFocus,
    int row,
    int column
  ) {
    return dtcr.getTableCellRendererComponent(
      table, format((String)value), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
  }

  private String format( String s ) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html><head></head><body>");

    int lastIdx = 0;
    final Matcher m = digits.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      final int idx1 = m.start();
      final int idx2 = m.end();
      sb.append(s, lastIdx, idx1);
      sb.append("<span style=\"color: #0000ff;\">");
      sb.append(s, idx1, idx2);
      sb.append("</span>");

      lastIdx = idx2;
    }
    if (lastIdx < s.length()) {
      sb.append(s.substring(lastIdx));
    }

    sb.append("</body></html>");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

The above assumes that your numbers are always non-negative integral numbers. If you need to support negative numbers or decimal numbers as well, you need to adjust the tokenizing logic in `format` accordingly.